# Developed application for iphone converting into android

Tags: iphone

I developed an app. for iphone. same app i need to develop for android.

i found some stuff about. sencha, phonegap,

Does it work efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

It'll be better if you'll develop it for Android again.

Comment: why? where will the app suffer?